# making a global variable in React to use clearInterval

Tags: reactjs, global-variables, countdown, clearinterval

I am learning React and I stumble upon a problem I could not find an answer for a few days already. I am trying to make an app similar to countdown app. in this app, I can make countdown runs but I cannot get access to timer function to use clearInterval since timer is restricted in its function scope. is there anyway I can use clearInterval ontimer so I can pause begin function? In javascript vanilla, I can declare timer as a global variable and get access to it anywhere, but in react I do not know how to do it. I will be much appreciate for your help

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Countdown extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state ={count:10};
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={()=>begin(this.state.count)}>start</button>
                <button>pause</button>
                <button>continue</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

const begin=(c)=>{
    let count = c;
    const timer = setInterval(countdown,1000);
    function countdown(){
        count=count-1
        if (count<0){
            clearInterval(timer);
            return; 
        }

        console.log(count)
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Countdown/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would rather define the begin function in the component class itself and declare the timer as a class property like

```
class Countdown extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state ={count:10};
        this.timer = null;
    }

    countdown = (count) => {
        count= count-1
        if (count<0){
            clearInterval(this.timer);
            return; 
        }

    }
    begin=() => {
      const count = this.state.count
      this.timer = setInterval(() => countdown(count),1000);

    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.begin}>start</button>
                <button>pause</button>
                <button>continue</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks, but I cannot really declare a const inside of the class like that, console gives me error of unexpected token.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, updated the code, you don't need to declare it as a constant

Comment: I have just declared countdown function inside of begin function before you posted, .and it works thank you very much now I can clearInterval on timer. by the way, if I remove const, it will give me another error "countdown is not defined"